# How to improve this question?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

What might I do to improve the question [How to gather data about how weight is distributed by feet on a surface over time?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/181419/81679)?  It is linked to a similar question that was upvoted a bunch, so wondering how I might improve it to make it more useful for the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just cast the last close vote on your question, and gave you a -1 for good measure.

I personally find it obnoxious to have to chase down pertinent information to a question.  No, I'm not going to follow a link to get such information.  A link to reference information, like to a datasheet, is OK.  Even then, if the question is about something specific in the datasheet, that small piece should be copied directly into the question.

I'm not getting paid to be here, and have no obligation to answer your question.  Put another way, you are asking me for a favor.  Expecting me to do your work for you in properly assembling a question so that I can then do you a favor is insulting and disrespectful.

Since I didn't follow the link, I don't know what you are asking, so I voted to close since the question is unclear.  The downvote is a way to say *screw you* for the disrespect.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain your thinking, I appreciate it.  Should we just delete the question or do you think it is salvageable?  I'll edit it again to try and improve it further, hopefully I get closer to the mark this time.

Answer (score 2):

One issue with your question is the video.

1. A potential respondent has to watch the video and try to figure out what's it all about.
2. The video itself is a marketing pitch for a product.  The technical aspects of data collection are not even mentioned.
   Were the subjects actually barefoot?  Or the toes are drawn for
   visualization during post-processing?  Why are all feet uniformly
   aligned North-South all the time?  Why is pressure uniform within each foot at the 1st frame?
3. The video may perish in the future.

You can't fix item 2 a this time.  (If you post your own data, that would be very interesting.  But that will happen later on.)
You can fix items 1 and 3 by posting a screenshot of the video and providing your own [cautious] description of what you think is going on there.

Comment: You actually paid more attention to that video than I did!

Comment: @Respawned  Few years ago, I had a chance to play with a Tekscan pressure mapper.

Comment: I've used an archive.org link now to make the link more permanent and reordered to put the description ahead of the video and embellished it.  Does that satisfy your points 1 and 3?

Comment: I've removed the video since it was not required, just extra information.